# The zoom for uiscrollview isn't working

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, zooming

I don't understand why the scrollview isn't working, because I followed advices from tutorials.

I created the `UIScrollView` that contains an `UIImageView` and I also added the method

```
 - (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
 {
   return imgv;
 }
```

and the `UIScrollViewDelegate` in the interface, but it isn't working.

Here is the code for the `UIScrollView`:

```
 imgv = [[UIImageView alloc]
                     initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1000, 500)];
 imgv.image = [UIImage imageWithData:retrievedData];

 scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 800, 800)];
 scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(imgv.image.size.width, imgv.image.size.height)];
 scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4;
 scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1;
 [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
 scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
 scrollView.delegate = self;

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(hideImageView)];

 [scrollView addSubview:imgv];
 [view addSubview:scrollView];
```

I would be thankful, if someone could figure out what the problem could be.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return `imgv` in your delegate method [viewForZoomingInScrollView:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html):

```
- (UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *) view {
    return imgv;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the imageView as a subview to the scrollview

```
[scrollView addSubview:imgv];
```

Comment: i was in hurry and didn't post that. sorry. I have this already.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are forgetting to set the frame of your imageView properly

```
self.imageView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.imageView.image.size.width, self.imageView.image.size.height);
```

Comment: The frame was set, but this way self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 800, 800)];

Comment: that's the frame of scrollView, not imageView

Comment: sorry. i meant imgv = [[UIImageView alloc]
            initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1000, 500)];