# The method - (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView isn't called

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, zooming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The zoom for uiscrollview isn’t working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567887/the-zoom-for-uiscrollview-isnt-working)

I posted a question yesterday, because the zoom for the UIScrollView isn't working. When pressing on a button, a UIScrollView appears, that contains an UIImage, but the problem is that I can't zoom by clicking or double-clicking on the image. I made a debug and the method

```
   - (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

doesn't get called. The question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567887/the-zoom-for-uiscrollview-isnt-working/13576137#13576137)

Sorry for asking the same question again. Thank you in advance. I wish you all the best!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the property UserInteractionEnabled of image view to YES. May be that can help

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it isn't working. :)

Answer (score 0):

Did u set the delegate of scrollview.First check it once...if delegate returns nil, nothing happens....so first set the delegate of UIScrollview.

Comment: unfortunately the delegate is set and it doesn't return nil. :)